# Mulesoft connecting to API with Basic Authentication but no password

Tags: api, http, authentication, mule, mule-studio

I am attempting to connect to the Insightly API through my mule esb project. Insightly requires that you use Basic Authentication to connect to there API and they provide you with an API key to use as your username for authentication but they tell you to leave the password blank.

When using the HTTPS Request endpoint a password is required in Basic Authentication, so this is an issue for me. I have tried using a property placeholder as the password and then leaving the placeholder value as blank, and this allows me to run the flow, but errors out upon deployment.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work, currently I have been using the deprecated http:outbound and inbound endpoints to make this work, but this is not a permanent solution, and I would like to get all of those deprecated endpoints over to the new HTTP Request connector.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the HTTP transport (http:outbound-endpoint) or connector (http:request)?

Comment: The connector (http:request)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MEL with an empty string:

```
<http:request path="/something" method="POST" config-ref="http">
    <http:basic-authentication username="USER" password="#['']" />
</http:request-config>
```

Or alternatively base64 the user and blank password and add the Authorization header yourself:

```
<http:request config-ref="http" path="/something" method="POST" doc:name="Request to BPM">
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Basic a2VybWl0OnBhc3N3b3JkMQ=="/>
    </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

Comment: I said that I was trying to get away from using http:outbound-enpoint I am trying to use http:request. It works just fine with the http:outbound-endpoint, but that connector is deprecated

Comment: I have tried both of those solutions, and I get a 401 each time.

Comment: Just tried both of those, and neither one worked. Still getting a 401

Comment: Sounds like they don't actually want a blank password then. Can you get this working in an external http client such as curl or postman?

Comment: I have not tried. to do that. I could be doing something wrong still. let me link code

Comment: Here is the request:

<http:request config-ref="workhorse-apiConsumer" method="POST" path="customer" doc:name="Call Mule API console to create spreadsheet." responseTimeout="30000">
                 <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="user(base 64 encoded)"/>
           </http:request-builder>
                </http:request>

Comment: And here is the config:

<http:request-config name="workhorse-apiConsumer" host="api.insight.ly" port="443" basePath="v2.1" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS"/>

Comment: If the basic auth from the connector doesn't work you can try sending the header yourself as you are doing above. However, the value should be something like ```value="#['Basic ' + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String('user:'.getBytes())]"```